# C# Launcher program(ConsoleApp) that launches other executables

Tags: c#, console, exe, launcher

I've written a launcher program that fires off a given number of executables, with the following code:

Process.Start(strPath2EXE);

The problem I'm running into is it seems I'm being limited to launching only about four copies of the executable. Is there a different way I can launch the executables without this limit? I'm hoping to run 10+ concurrently.

Here is the error from the event log:
EventType clr20r3, P1 launcher.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4bec3901, P4 system, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4889de7a, P7 39f5, P8 288, P9 system.componentmodel.win32, P10 NIL.

Comment: Please provide more details. Is it possible to have for example stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to the virtual "limit" you imagine. There is no such thing. You can start as many processes as you want.

That's not much to go with. Debug the app and provide a callstack. I suspect some of the executables require elevation, and your launcher is not elevated. Thus perhaps a security exception.